# SQL Server: Inconsistencies in date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table #temp
(
  A date
)

insert into #temp(A)
values(GETDATE())
insert into #temp(A)
values(GETDATE()-1)
```

Now when I query the table as

`select A from #temp where A>=GETDATE() and A<=GETDATE()`

I get no records
But `GETDATE()` record value should satisfy my where condition, shouldn't it at least pass me one record?

Please guide me if I am missing some point here.

Comment: what do you think `getdate()-1` gives you?

Comment: 1) First of all why you have a comma in `A date,`? Is it a typo? because that code won't run. 2) Are you looking for `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: `GETDATE() - 1` subtracts one calendar day from `GETDATE()`.

Comment: @SanyShaikh . . . `GETDATE()` has a time component and you are not taking that into account.  Your condition is equivalent to `a = getdate()` and that is only true for a fleeting instant.

Comment: Did you tested it @Sami? The code should works well on SSMS 18 or ADS, even so it is not well formatted and the comma should not be there (I tested it on both app to confirm it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do conversion, so it seems :

```
where a >= convert(date, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())) and 
      a <= convert(date, getdate());
```

Your `where` clause comparing date as :

```
where a >= '2020-04-21 16:01:27.277' and a <= '2020-04-21 16:01:27.277'
```

So, you need to convert date because `getdate()`will also return time portions.

Since your `where` clause looks for single day so you can do :

```
where a = convert(date, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh is right.

`GETDATE()` gives the present `DATEIME` value. When you insert it into a `DATE` column, SQL Server *[coerces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)* -- silently typecasts -- the `DATETIME` to a `DATE` before inserting it.

But when you use it in a `WHERE` clause, SQL Server coerces the `DATE` from your column into a `DATETIME` value by turning `2020-04-20` into `2020-04-20 00:00:00`. That can't be the same as `GETDATE()` except during the first few milliseconds of each day. (Meaning you or your test krewe are extremely unlikely to catch it equal.)

Comment: SQL Server will convert the `DATE` to `DATETIME`, because `GETDATE()` returns a `DATETIME` and a `DATETIME` has high [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than `DATE`

Comment: O. Jones, Tiny fix: "except once a day" -> should be: "except during 3 millisecond each day". During that period of time you can have multiple values.